# Python unicode string literals :: what's the difference between '\u0391' and u'\u0391'

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-literals

I am using Python 2.7.3. Can anybody explain the difference between the literals:

```
'\u0391'
```

and:

```
u'\u0391'
```

and the different way they are echoed in the REPL below (especially the extra slash added to a1):

```
>>> a1='\u0391'
>>> a1
'\\u0391'
>>> type(a1)
<type 'str'>
>>> 
>>> a2=u'\u0391'
>>> a2
u'\u0391'
>>> type(a2)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in Python 3, these are identical, and both of type `str`, because `str` is now Unicode (but `b'\u0391'` is still equivalent to your `a1`, except it's of type `bytes`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use unicode escapes (`\uabcd`) in a unicode string literal. They have no meaning in a byte string. A Python 2 Unicode literal (`u'some text'`) is a different type of Python object from a python byte string (`'some text'`).

It's like using `\t` versus `\T`; the former has meaning in python literals (it's interpreted as a tab character), the latter just means a backslash and a capital T (two characters).

To help understand the difference between Unicode and byte strings, please do read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html); I can also recommend the [Joel Spolsky on Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Note: in Python 3, the same differences apply, but `'some text'` is a Unicode string literal, and `b'some text'` is the bytestring syntax.

Comment: +1. If you want a `str` with `\u0391` in it, you need to pick an encoding, and write, e.g., `u'\u0391'.encode('utf-8')`, which will give you `'\xce\x91'`.

Comment: If u'some text' is different than 'some text' how do you explain: u'a'=='a' which evaluates to True ?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: Python auto-decodes to Unicode when comparing the two. You can compare floats to integers too, doesn't make them the same type though. Python decodes the byte string to attempt the test; try `u'\u0391' == u'\u0391'.encode('utf8')` and you'll get a warning (decoding is done from ASCII by default).

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: The same way `1 == 1.0` is True. Equality doesn't necessarily mean identity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, I deleted my comment after you edited yours, and before you responded. (But are you sure it's from ASCII rather than `sys.getdefaultencoding()`? Of course that's usually ASCII in 2.7 anyway…)

Comment: @abarnert: exactly; I didn't want to complicate things more, let alone give people the idea that setting the default encoding is a good thing to do. ASCII is the default encoding on Python 2, and yes, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is consulted when auto-converting unicode to bytes or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to C, in Python a string can be enclosed in simple quotes (`'`) as well as double quotes (`"`) -- leaving aside the triple-double quotes `"""`.

Thus, `'\u0391'` is only a string containing the letters `\`, `u`, `0`, `3`, `9` and `1`. When pretty printing this string, the `\` is escaped via another `\`.

On the contrary, having a `u` in front makes the string to be considered Unicode and all escapes are evaluated. Thus, `u'\u0391'` is interpreted as "the Unicode string containing codepoint `0391`" which is different from the above.